# Aplicación Java no genera reportes en servidor Tomcat

Tags: java, netbeans, tomcat

Realicé un pequeño software de consultas en Java que hace reportes en iReport. Mi problema es que corriendo con el Glassfish del NetBeans (localmente) la aplicación funciona 100% pero, al subir el .WAR en el servidor que tengo que corre Tomcat, no sale nada: una página en blanco.
Adjunto imágenes con sus respectivas ubicaciones dentro del servidor y en mi pc local, así para poder tener una mejor vista del problema. Lo peor es que no hay ningún código de error.[image]

Comment: Si el WAR ha sido creado para subirse a GlassFish probablemente no funcione en Tomcat. GlassFish es un servidor de aplicaciones que te proporciona muchas de las dependencias (JARs) que necesita tu app, por lo que el WAR creado para trabajar con este quizá no las incluya. Por otra parte, Tomcat es solamente un contenedor de Servlets por lo que el WAR que se quiera usar sobre este debe incluir todas las dependencias necesarias.

Comment: Hola! gracias por contestar!! lo compilaré de vuelta pero con Tomcat como servidor en NetBeans.

Comment: También hace lo mismo en el servidor Grassfish.

Comment: Entonces vas a tener que revisar los logs de tu aplicación para ver que está ocurriendo.

Comment: Resuelto, era la ruta donde se guardan las imágenes. Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar este problema, seguí los siguientes pasos:

Paso 1: Verificar la ruta de las imágenes.
Lo primero que hice fue verificar la ruta de las imágenes en mi informe. Revisé si estaba utilizando rutas relativas o absolutas y si la estructura de directorios era correcta.

Paso 2: Usar rutas relativas.
Para evitar problemas con la ruta, decidí utilizar rutas relativas en lugar de rutas absolutas. Las rutas relativas son más flexibles y portables, ya que se ajustan automáticamente según la ubicación del archivo de informe.

Paso 3: Colocar las imágenes en la ubicación adecuada.
Asegurarse de que las imágenes estén ubicadas en el directorio correcto, relativo al archivo del informe. En mi caso, coloqué las imágenes en un subdirectorio llamado "img" dentro del directorio del informe.

Paso 4: Configurar la ruta en el reporte.
En el diseñador de informes de Jasper Reports, accedí a las propiedades de las imágenes y configuré la ruta utilizando una expresión que apuntaba al directorio "img" que había creado previamente. Por ejemplo: "img/image1.png".

Paso 5: Verificar la vista previa.
Guardé los cambios en el informe y luego revisé la vista previa para asegurarme de que las imágenes se mostraran correctamente. A veces, esto puede revelar problemas adicionales con la ruta o la ubicación de las imágenes.

Paso 6: Exportar y probar el reporte.
Finalmente, exporté el informe y lo probé en diferentes entornos y plataformas para garantizar que las imágenes se mostraran correctamente y que la ruta funcionara en todas las situaciones.

Conclusión:
Al seguir estos pasos, logré corregir el problema de la ruta de las imágenes en mi informe de Jasper Reports. Utilizar rutas relativas y asegurarme de que las imágenes estuvieran en la ubicación correcta fueron aspectos clave para resolver el problema.

Espero que esta solución sea de ayuda para otros desarrolladores que enfrenten problemas similares con las rutas de los recursos en Jasper Reports. Siempre es importante verificar la estructura de directorios y utilizar rutas relativas para asegurarse de que el informe funcione correctamente en diferentes entornos.

Comment: Hola Paco, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos,  aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: @MarcePuente ojo, esto no era un comentario, ¡es el OP respondiendo (incompletamente) a su pregunta!

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y detalla cuál era el problema. ¿Ruta incorrecta? Lee [answer]. Luego, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.

Comment: Aguante Chat-GPT

Comment: Acá todo es llorar porque esto por aquello, no pusiste coma... te falta acento... que bárbaro.

Comment: @MarcePuente ¿ya te parece "completa" la respuesta? necesitas algo más?

Comment: Maestro, ni Dalí hubiese creado esta pintura!!, saludos!!

Comment: Hola Paco, entonces usaste IA para obtener esta respuesta? @Paco

Comment: Un abrazo  @MarcePuente

Comment: @Jorgesys no, realicé un análisis profundo del problema y traté de ser los más explícito posible.